# python: передача в функции параметров в виде словаря и добавление своих значений

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, словари, dict

подскажите как компактно, красиво и корректно передать в функцию параметры, содержащиеся в словаре + добавить свои параметры

если над просто передать значения, то проблем нет:

```
data = {
    'v1':   123,
    'v3':   3.1415,
    'v2':   'abc'
}


def func(v1, v2, v3):
    print(v1, v2, v3, sep='\n')


func(**data)
```

а как быть, если я хочу заменить одно значение другим или добавить новое?

в JavaScript можно делать так:

```
{...data, v1: 987}
```

**а какой-нибудь короткий и красивый аналог в питоне есть?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете просто добавить именованный аргумент *перед* словарем `**kwargs`:

```
kw = {"a":1, "b":2}
def myfunc(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

myfunc(**kw)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

myfunc(c=3, **kw)
# {'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}

mydict = {"e":4, "f":5}
myfunc(**mydict, **kw)
# {'e': 4, 'f': 5, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

для замены значения можно так:

```
myfunc(**dict(kw, a=100))
# {'a': 100, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: да, вариант работает, причем не важно перед или после ставить новый параметр (вроде как проверил - оба варианта прошли), но вот как быть когда надо ЗАМЕНИТЬ параметр? т.е. в словаре уже есть такой параметр, условно `**{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, b=2` - получается ошибка `got multiple values for keyword argument`, поэтому и привел способ из JS - там это происходит автоматически - если был старый параметр СЛЕВА, то он заменится на параметр, который указан СПРАВА, что очень удобно и компактно

Comment: ну я привел последний пример с заменой же.

Comment: не заметил :) да, вариант хороший, спасибо, конечно если бы еще от `dict` избавиться можно было, но наверное большую компактность уже не получить

Comment: @Zhihar можно так извратиться: `func(**{**data, "v2": 10})`

Answer (score 1):

Словари можно распаковывать так:

```py
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> {**d, 'c': 3}  # Распаковка внутрь другого словаря
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>>
```

Соответственно, в вашем коде можно сделать так:

```py
data = {
    'v1': 123,
    'v3': 3.1415,
    'v2': 'abc'
}


def func(**vs):
    print(vs)


func(**{**data, 'v4': 456})
```

*(Этот вариант ближе всего к приведённому в вопросе способу на JavaScript)*

Answer (score 1):

Словари можно объединять оператором `|`:

```py
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> d1 | d2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Соответственно, в вашем случае можно сделать так:

```py
data = {
    'v1': 123,
    'v3': 3.1415,
    'v2': 'abc'
}

additional = {
    'v4': 456
}


def func(**vs):
    print(vs)


func(**(data | additional))  # распаковываем результат операции
```